# Get the coordinate of the current first cell on the screen of device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have table view to display my data. And when I scroll my table view, the first cell is hidden, the second cell or third cell is become the first cell on my screen of device. So have anyway to know it as the current first cell on the screen of device? Or get the current coordinate of it with the screen of device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods in UITableView that may help you:

This one returns an `NSArray` with the visible cells.

```
- (NSArray *)visibleCells;
```

This one returns an `NSArray` with `NSIndexPath` of the visible rows.

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Comment: With the array indexPathsForVisibleRows. How do I know if I touch on the first cell into this array or the another cell into this array?

Comment: You did not ask about touching. You asked about knowing the visible cells. There is a method in UITableView `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` that will get called when the user taps on a cell and let you know the indexPath of the selected row. Then you could cross reference this with the indexpaths returned from the method mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

lee you can identify the cell by it's tag value `cell.tag=indexPath.row;`

Comment: his question is the visible cells of a tableview

Comment: then maybe you should expound your answer

Comment: @Shubham It's out of my question.